# How to make a class field [list] read-only in python?

Tags: python, oop

i have self.some_field = [] in my class
Im enquiring is there a way to make this list read-only like a property?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make it, indeed, a property...: e.g., in `__init__`

```
self._some_field = []
```

and then later in the class's body:

```
@property
def some_field(self):
    return self._some_field
```

Note that this does **not** make the list itself immutable: what will fail is an *assignment* like, say,

```
self.some_field = 'bah'
```

**not** the call of a mutator, like, say,

```
self.some_field.append('blah')
```

If you want to make the field immutable, it cannot be a list, by definition (since a list is a mutable sequence) -- it must be some other type of sequence (an immutable one) which you need to define for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the attribute, then make it a read-only property. If you mean the list itself, then use a tuple instead since they're immutable.